# Custom Wordpress Contact Form with Javascript Google Maps Reverse Geolocation won't work

Tags: plugins

I am really baffled by this, I've adapted the sitepoint tutorial contact form with additional fields and google maps reverse geolocation.  I have some strange errors that have driven me crazy.  I can get it work in ordinary html, but when I create the custom plugin code and send it to wordpress the javascript and jquery don't work even though the scripts have been resisted and enqueued properly and I can read them all in the head of the wordpress page.

This is what I am trying to achieve (active development site) http://www.daviescoachesonline.co.uk/new/wp-content/plugins/2015-davies-contact/index.html (works perfectly) on my localhost, yet, the map's don't render on my remote site and when I activate my custom plugin all I get is the basic form output in html, nothing else.

this can be seen here.

http://www.daviescoachesonline.co.uk/new/day-tours/

plugin code for the custom plugin is here...

```
    <?php   
    function contact_setup() {
        // Register the script like this for a plugin:
        wp_register_script( 'bootstrap-min', plugins_url( 'js/bootstrap.min.js', __FILE__ ) );
        wp_register_script( 'placepicker', plugins_url( 'js/jquery.placepicker.js', __FILE__ ),array('jquery') );
        wp_register_script( 'placepicker-min', plugins_url( 'js/jquery.placepicker.min.js', __FILE__ ),array('jquery') );
        wp_register_script( 'dtpicker', plugins_url( 'js/jquery.simple-dtpicker.js', __FILE__ ), array('jquery') ); 
        wp_register_script( 'googlemapslibrary', 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&#038;sensor=false&#038;libraries=places&#038', __FILE__, false );
        wp_register_script( 'placepickershort', plugins_url( 'js/placepicker.js', __FILE__) );
        wp_register_script( 'appenddtpicker', plugins_url('js/appenddtpicker.js',__FILE__));


        wp_enqueue_script('bootstrap-min');
        wp_enqueue_script('placepicker');
        wp_enqueue_script('placepicker-min');
        wp_enqueue_script('dtpicker');
        wp_enqueue_script('googlemapslibrary');
        wp_enqueue_script('placepickershort');
        wp_enqueue_script('appenddtpicker');

    }



    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'contact_setup' );    


    function contact_styles() {
        wp_register_style( 'jquery-ui', plugins_url('css/jquery-ui.css', __FILE__));
        wp_register_style( 'bootstrap-theme-min', plugins_url( 'css/bootstrap-theme-min.css', __FILE__ ), array(), '20152208', 'all' );
        wp_register_style( 'bootstrap-min', plugins_url( 'css/bootstrap-min.css', __FILE__ ), array(), '20152208', 'all' );
        wp_register_style( 'contact-style', plugins_url( 'css/contact-style.css', __FILE__ ), array(), '20152208', 'all' );
        wp_register_style( 'jquery-simple-datepicker', plugins_url( 'css/jquery.simple-dtpicker.css', __FILE__ ), array(), '20152208', 'all' );

        wp_enqueue_script('bootstrap-theme-min');
        wp_enqueue_script('bootstrap-min');
        wp_enqueue_script('contact-style');
        wp_enqueue_script('jquery-simple-datepicker');  
    }

    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'contact_styles' ); 


    function html_form_code() {
        echo '<div class="form-cont" data-example>'."\r\n";    
        echo '<div class="form-box">'."\r\n";
        echo '<div class="form-group">'."\r\n";
        echo '<form action="' . esc_url( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ) . '" method="post">'."\r\n";
        echo '<p>'."\r\n";
        echo '<div class="form-group">'."\r\n";
            /*name input*/
        echo 'Your Name (required) <br />'."\r\n";
        echo '<input type="text" class="fm-text" name="fm_name" placeholder="Your Name" pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9 ]+" value="' . ( isset( $_POST["fm_name"] ) ? esc_attr( $_POST["fm_name"] ) : '' ) . '" size="40" />'."\r\n";
        echo '</div>'."\r\n";
            /*email input*/
        echo '<div class="form-group">'."\r\n";
        echo 'Your Email (required) <br />'."\r\n";
        echo '<input type="email" class="fm-text" name="fm_email" placeholder="Your Email Address" value="' . ( isset( $_POST["fm_email"] ) ? esc_attr( $_POST["fm_email"] ) : '' ) . '" size="40" />'."\r\n";
        echo '</div>'."\r\n";

            /*telephone input*/
        echo '<div class="form-group">'."\r\n";
        echo 'Your Telephone Number (required) <br />'."\r\n";
        echo '<input type="fm-text" placeholder="Your Telephone Number" name="fm_telephone" value="' . ( isset( $_POST["fm_telephone"] ) ? esc_attr( $_POST["fm_telephone"] ) : '' ) . '" size="40" />'."\r\n";
        echo '</div>'."\r\n";
            //
            //
            /*pick up points start here */
        echo '<div class="form-group">'."\r\n";
        echo 'Pick Up Point (required)<br />'."\r\n";
        echo '<input type="text" class="placepicker form-control" placeholder="Choose your pickup point" data-map-container-id="collapseOne" name="fm_pickup" value="' . ( isset( $_POST["fm_pickup"] ) ? esc_attr( $_POST["fm_pickup"] ) : '' ) . '" size="40" />'."\r\n";
        echo '</div>'."\r\n";

        echo '<div id="collapseOne" class="collapse">'."\r\n";
        echo '<div class="placepicker-map thumbnail"></div>'."\r\n";
        echo '</div>'."\r\n";

            /*via alternate pick up point (optional)*/
        echo '<div class="form-group">'."\r\n";
        echo 'Additional Pick Up Point (Optional)<br />'."\r\n";
        echo '<input type="text" class="placepicker form-control" placeholder="Choose an additional optional pick up point" data-map-container-id="collapsetwo" name="fm_via" value="' . ( isset( $_POST["fm_via"] ) ? esc_attr( $_POST["fm_via"] ) : '' ) . '" size="40" />'."\r\n";
        echo '</div>'."\r\n";

        echo '<div id="collapsetwo" class="collapse">'."\r\n";
        echo '<div class="placepicker-map thumbnail"></div>'."\r\n";
        echo '</div>'."\r\n";

            /*destination */
        echo '<div class="form-group">'."\r\n";
        echo 'Destination (required)<br />'."\r\n";
        echo '<input type="text" class="placepicker form-control" placeholder="Type in your destination" data-map-container-id="collapsethree" name="fm_destination" value="' . ( isset( $_POST["fm_destination"] ) ? esc_attr( $_POST["fm_destination"] ) : '' ) . '" size="40" />'."\r\n";
        echo '</div>'."\r\n";

        echo '<div id="collapsethree" class="collapse">'."\r\n";
        echo '<div class="placepicker-map thumbnail"></div>'."\r\n";
        echo '</div>'."\r\n";

            /*Return or Single */
        echo '<div class="form-group">';
        echo '<label>With Return:  ';
        echo '<input type="radio" class="fm-text" value="' . ( isset( $_POST["fm_booking_type"] ) ? esc_attr( $_POST["fm_booking_type"] ) : '' ) . '" name="fm_booking_type" checked/>';
        echo '</label>';
        echo '</div>';
        echo '<div class="form-group">';    
        echo '<label>One Way Only:  ';
        echo '<input type="radio" class="fm-text" value="' . ( isset( $_POST["fm_booking_type"] ) ? esc_attr( $_POST["fm_booking_type"] ) : '' ) . '" name="fm_booking_type" />';
        echo '</label>';
        echo '</div>';

            /*number in party*/
        echo '<div class="form-group">';
        echo '<label>Number in Party';
        echo '<input class="text" type="number" id="party_size" value="' . ( isset( $_POST["fm_party_size"] ) ? esc_attr( $_POST["fm_party_size"] ) : '' ) . '" name="fm_party_size">';
        echo '</label>';
        echo '</div>';

            /*overnight bags*/
        echo '<div class="form-group">';
        echo '<select id="luggage" name="luggage" value="' . ( isset( $_POST["fm_luggage"] ) ? esc_attr( $_POST["fm_luggage"] ) : '' ) . '" >';
        echo '<option>Overnight Bags</option>';
        echo '<option>Small Ruck Sacks</option>';
        echo '<option>Suitcases</option>';
        echo '<option>Golf Bags</option>';
        echo '<option>Sports Kits</option>';
        echo '</select>';
        echo '</div>';


        echo '<div class="form-group">';
        echo '<label>Date and Time of Departure';
        echo '<input type="text" value="' . ( isset( $_POST["date11"] ) ? esc_attr( $_POST["date11"] ) : '' ) . '" name="date11" />';
        echo '</label>';
        echo '</div>';
        echo '<div class="form-group">';
        echo '<label>Date and Time of return';
        echo '<input type="text" value="' . ( isset( $_POST["date12"] ) ? esc_attr( $_POST["date12"] ) : '' ) . '" name="date12" />';
        echo '</label>';
        echo '</div>';

    ?>

        <script type="text/javascript">
                                    $(function(){
                                        $('*[name=date10]').appendDtpicker({
                                            "closeOnSelected": true
                                        });
                                    });
                                    $(function(){
                                        $('*[name=date11]').appendDtpicker({
                                            "closeOnSelected": true
                                        });
                                    });
                                </script>
    <?php 
            /*Additional Message */
        echo 'Any Other Requirements or Pick Up Points';
        echo '<textarea rows="10" cols="35" name="message">' . ( isset( $_POST["message"] ) ? esc_attr( $_POST["message"] ) : '' ) . '</textarea>';
        echo '</p>';
        echo '<p><input type="submit" name="submitted" value="Send"/></p>';
        echo '</form>';
        echo '</div><!--end form-group-->';
        echo '</div><!--end form-box-->';
        echo '<div><!--end form-cont-->';
    }

    function deliver_mail() {

        // if the submit button is clicked, send the email
        if ( isset( $_POST['submitted'] ) ) {

            // sanitize form values
            $ct_name    = sanitize_text_field( $_POST["fm_name"] );
            $ct_email   = sanitize_email( $_POST["fm_email"] );
            $ct_telephone = sanitize_text_field($_POST["fm_telephone"]);
            $ct_subject = "Online Enquiry";

            //sanitise location information
            $ct_pickup = sanitize_text_field($_POST['fm_pickup']);
            $ct_via = sanitize_text_field($_POST['fm_via']);
            $ct_destination = sanitize_text_field($_POST['fm_destination']);

            //sanitise additional infomration//
            $ct_booking_type = ($_POST['fm_booking_type']);
            $ct_party_size = ($_POST['fm_party_size']);
            $ct_luggage = ($_POST['fm_luggage']);

            $ct_message = esc_textarea( $_POST["message"] );
            $ct_date11 = sanitize_text_field($_POST['date11']);
            $ct_date12 = sanitize_text_field($_POST['date12']);

            // get the blog administrator's email address
            $to = get_option( 'admin_email' );

            $headers = "From: $ct_name <$ct_email>" . "\r\n";

            // If email has been process for sending, display a success message
            if ( wp_mail( $to, $ct_subject, $ct_message, $headers)) {
                echo '<div>';
                echo '<p>Thanks for contacting Us, we will be in touch soon.</p>';
                echo '</div>';
                echo $to, $ct_name, $ct_email, $ct_telephone, $ct_subject, $ct_pickup, $ct_via, $ct_destination, $ct_booking_type, $ct_luggage, $ct_date11, $ct_date12, $message, $headers;
            } else {
                echo 'An unexpected error occurred';
            }
        }
    }

    function cf_shortcode() {
        ob_start();
        deliver_mail();
        html_form_code();

        return ob_get_clean();
    }

    add_shortcode( 'sitepoint_contact_form', 'cf_shortcode' );

    ?>
```

I am learning and I fully admit that there's huge gaps in my knowledge so any help will be appreciated and gratefully received.  I've done normal HTML/CSS and some PHP in my past, Javascript is a weakness for me, but wordpress is making my life really frustrating lol.  Anyhow please help.

Comment: I've been plugging away at it and have found out that if I paste in the <script></script> links found at the top of the web page in the header I can get the plugin to work more or less as intended, so I'm clearly doing something wrong with the register and enquiring scripts set up in wordpress.  I can't see what that is if anyone can help?  Thanks :)

Comment: strange thing, when developing I used this jQuery library to create my html form (http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js), but the site references this one (the default included in wordpress) http://www.daviescoachesonline.co.uk/new/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.11.3'  I made sure that they were both the same version as I was mindful of this when developing the form, and I've checked them both, though one the wordpress one ends with 'no conflict' on the last line.  All other entries look identical.

Comment: I've had to cheat and use and IFRAME :(  I know it's less than ideal but done is better than perfect in this case.  If anyone can correct the above though I'd still love to find out why my code don't work.